# Why is b'\x02' not the same as the value 2 or int(2) in Python?

Tags: python, compare, byte

I have a PC sending the byte value 2 to a Raspberry Pi.

But I can't figure out why the Python program does not evaluate to true when it receives the value.

If I print the values received it writes b'\x02' as output.

```
import serial

def GetSerialData():
    x = ser.inWaiting()
    if x > 0:
        received_data = ser.read(x)
        print (received_data)
    return x


ser = serial.Serial ("/dev/ttyAMA0", 9600)
try:
    while True:
        SData = GetSerialData ()
        if ( SData == b'\x02'):
            print ("Ok - value is 2")

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    ser.close()
```

Comment: You are probably reading more than one byte. Depending on the order in which bytes are send (big endian or little endian) the `b'\x02'` may be the first or the last, but `SData` will contain more bytes than that so it would not be equal to it in any case (btw side tip, you may prefer passing `ser` as a parameter to `GetSerialData` instead of implicitly using it as a global variable)

Comment: Can you provide the code the PC is running, as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GetSerialData` function does not appear to actually return the serial data. It *prints* the serial data, but then you never refer to `received_data` after that, and instead return `x`, which appears to be an integer representing the size of the response.

Instead of returning x, try returning `received_data`.

```
def GetSerialData():
    x = ser.inWaiting()
    if x > 0:
        return ser.read(x)
    else:
        return b"" #or whatever value is appropriate when no data has been sent yet
```

Comment: My bad !! Stupid mistake to be honest. I'm returning the number of bytes in the serial buffer where as I should return the actual data. Once I changed the code to return `received_data` it works as expected. The suggestion to `return ser.read(x)` got me on track. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

`\x02` is ASCII code for hex 02, which is `STX` (start of text).
`\x32` is the ASCII for the digit `2`.
If `SData` is an integer or any non-(binary) string, remember to convert it to string with `str(SData)`.
Also, in general, `b'A' != 'A'`. You want to use `.encode('ascii')` to convert a Python string to an ASCII binary string.

```
>>> binary_A_from_string = 'A'.encode('ascii')
>>> binary_A_from_string
b'A'

>>> binary_A = '\x41' # ASCII 41 (dec 65) is 'A'
>>> binary_A
b'A'

>>> binary_A == 'A'
False
>>> binary_A == binary_A_from_string
True
```

This is because Python sees binary ASCII strings as different from standard Python strings.

Also, make sure that the information read is actually one byte long.